# How can we disable frame limitting / vsync in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, 3d, game-engine, vulkan

I just started to take a look at Vulkan and I came accross a little problem:

**Is there a way to disable vsync / frame limitting and go above the screen refresh rate using vulkan please ?** *(I'm using Node Vulkan but it's quite the same calls than on regular vulkan).*

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

By selecting [`VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPresentModeKHR) upon Swapchain creation.